# MySql select with Limit 1 when using a join with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm actually trying to select one record from `amgb` using a limit while doing a join with `amga`.

My tables are like this:

**amga**

```
"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemName"                  "itemCountry"   "userId"
"1"     "US1"       "T001"          "Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "US"            "1"
"2"     "CA2"       "T002"          "Samsung Galaxy Note 6"     "CA"            "2"
"3"     "UK3"       "T003"          "Samsung Galaxy Note 7"     "UK"            "3"
```

**amgb**

```
"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName"     "userId"
"1"     "US1"       "T001"          "front.jpg"         "1"
"2"     "US1"       "T001"          "side-left.jpg"     "1"
"3"     "US1"       "T001"          "side-right.jpg"    "1"
"4"     "US1"       "T001"          "back.jpg"          "1"
"5"     "CA2"       "T002"          "front.jpg"         "2"
"6"     "CA2"       "T002"          "side-left.jpg"     "2"
"7"     "CA2"       "T002"          "side-right.jpg"    "2"
"8"     "CA2"       "T002"          "back.jpg"          "2"
"9"     "UK3"       "T003"          "front.jpg"         "3"
```

In plain language, this amounts to something like this:
`select itemName from amga where itemId = 'US1' and userId = 1 along with 1 itemImageName from amgb where itemId = sameOneAsBefore and userId = sameOneAsBefore`

The end result I'm hoping for is as simple as this:
`Samsung Galaxy Note 5 | front.jpg` -  that's itemName from `amga` and itemImageName from `amgb` where userId = 1 and itemId = US1

But I dont see where I'm going wrong despite all the joins and everything else being correct. What could be causing the problem `/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'b.userId' in 'on clause' */`

```
SELECT  a.itemName, b.itemImageName 
FROM amga a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        itemImageName
    FROM
        amgb
    LIMIT 1
) b
ON a.userId = b.userId and a.itemId = b.itemId  
WHERE a.userId = 1 and a.itemId = 'US1';
```

Comment: You don't have a column named `UserId` (or `itemId` for that matter) in your `Left Join`.  The only column you have is `itemImageName`.  The error tells you that directly.

Comment: I have it in the ON. Why select it again in there?

Comment: You can't `Join On` a column that doesn't exist.  If you don't select it in your sub-select, it doesn't exist.  You need to add `UserId` and `ItemId` to the `Left Join` `Select` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If subquery returns one column and no more than one record you can include it as column in query:

```
SELECT  a.itemName,
  (SELECT itemImageName
    FROM amgb b
    WHERE a.userId = b.userId AND a.itemId = b.itemId
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS itemImageName
FROM amga a 
WHERE a.userId = 1 AND a.itemId = 'US1';
```

Comment: `If subquery returns one column and no more than one record you can include it as column in query` - Yes, it'll return only one column. So what you've done is correct right?

Comment: Yes as it return just one value or null (if no records), more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/scalar-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:-

```
SELECT  a.itemName, b.itemImageName 
FROM amga a 
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT itemId, userId, itemImageName
           FROM amgb
           LIMIT 1
          ) b
ON a.userId = b.userId and a.itemId = b.itemId  
WHERE a.userId = 1 and a.itemId = 'US1';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  a.itemName, b.itemImageName 
FROM amga a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        itemImageName, userId
    FROM
        amgb
    LIMIT 1
) b
ON a.userId = b.userId and a.itemId = b.itemId  
WHERE a.userId = 1 and a.itemId = 'US1';
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
SELECT  a.itemName, b.itemImageName 
FROM amga a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        itemImageName
    FROM
        amgb b
    LIMIT 1
) <= 1
ON a.userId = b.userId and a.itemId = b.itemId  
WHERE a.userId = 1 and a.itemId = 'US1';
```